# Is there a CORS support for Office 365 Mail REST API?

Tags: office365, office365-apps, outlook-restapi

Is there a CORS supports for Office 365 Mail REST API?

I know it has support for Sharepoint and Files REST APIs.

If yes, is there any example for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's the article that shows you how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-CORS-to-access-files-in-Office-365